# Как установить свою ширину при которой navbar перейдет в мини вид?

Tags: bootstrap

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как установить свою ширину при которой navbar перейдет в мини вид? Пример: http://cs7002.vk.me/c607419/v607419472/665c/AtlXQ7Sbrks.jpg ?

Comment: @andreyu, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться. @andreyu, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Скомпилировать](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)  со своими значениями — см. параметры `grid-float-breakpoint` и `grid-float-breakpoint-max`, которые скорее всего ссылаются на `screen-sm`.